# Save images to photo album one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, boolean

I have images in document folder and getting images then saving to custom photo album. I used BOOL flag NO once the images are stored to photo album. But when i launch the app it's not storing to photo album.

viewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL savealbum;
```

viewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (_savealbum) {
        [self savePhoto];
    }
}

- (void)savePhoto 
{
    NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"],
                       nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [photos count]; i++) {
        image1 = [photos objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.library saveImage:image1 toAlbum:@"Room Template" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            _savealbum = NO;

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL isSaved=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"photosave"];
if (!isSaved) {
            [self savePhoto];
    [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"photosave"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

//

```
    -(void)savePhoto{
    NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"],
                       nil] ;
    for(int i=0; i<[photos count]; i++){
            image1=[photos objectAtIndex:i];
            [self.library saveImage:image1 toAlbum:@"Art" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                //   arappdelegate.isNotSaved=FALSE;
                if (error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
                }
            }];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>

{
    BOOL isFirst;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL isFirst;
- (BOOL) isFirstRun;

AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSLog(@"isfirst:%d",[self isFirstRun]);
    }
- (BOOL) isFirstRun
{
    Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([Defaults objectForKey:@"savealbum"])
    {
        //if application running in second time
        isFirst=NO;
        NSLog(@"isSecondRun:%d",isFirst);
        return NO;
    }
    //if application running in first time
    isFirst=YES;
    NSLog(@"isFirstRun:%d",isFirst);

    [Defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"savealbum"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```

In viewController.m:

```
if(appDelegate.isFirst==1)
{
[self savePhoto];
}

-(void)savePhoto{
    NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"],
                       nil] ;
    for(int i=0; i<[photos count]; i++){
            image1=[photos objectAtIndex:i];
            [self.library saveImage:image1 toAlbum:@"Art" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                   appDelegate.isFirst=NO;
                if (error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
                }
            }];
        }
}
```

Hope it may helps

Comment: can you please help this

Comment: Have you imported AppDelegate.h file in viewcontroller

Comment: can you please post the NSLog message

Comment: I didn't get any NSLog

Comment: when i run the app i didn't get any NSLog from AppDelegate

Comment: appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear:%d",appDelegate.isFirst);

Comment: viewWillAppear:0  first time run the app

Comment: In AppDelegate First time run: isFirstRun:1  isfirst:1.. But in viewcontroller.m : viewWillAppear:0

Comment: viewWillAppear always 0 first & second time run

Comment: please help this issue

Comment: print appdelegate.isfirst value in NSLog in ViewDidLoad